# Why String concatenate null with + operator and throws NullPointerException with concate() method

Tags: java, string

Here is my class, where i am concatenating two string. 
String concatenate with `null` using + operator execute smoothly but throws `NullPointerException` with `concate()` method.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str="abc";
        String strNull=null;

        System.out.println(strNull+str);

        str.concat(strNull);
    }
}
```

can anybody tell me the reason behind it ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Case 1:**

```
 System.out.println(strNull+str);  // will not give you exception
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)(String conversion)

> **If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null"** (four
>   ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null"
>   is used instead.

**Case 2:**

```
str.concat(strNull);  //NullPointer exception
```

If you see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.concat%28java.lang.String%29) of `concat(String str)` it uses `str.length();` so it would be like `null.length()` giving you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: so why doesn't `System.out.println(strNull+str)` give an output of "nullabc"?

Comment: @Blip `If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null"` will not throw nullpointer because `toString()` is not called on it

Comment: Ok so `null + str` is converted to `"null"+"abc"` according to the example above. so the output should be "nullabc"?

Comment: it will give nullabc as output. i checked it before. but i want to know why different Strategies of + and concate()

Answer (score 8):

If you see in java.lang.String source, and use null as parameter. NPE is thrown 
in first line in length() method.

```
public String concat(String str) {
    int otherLen = str.length();//This is where NullPointerException is thrown
    if (otherLen == 0) {
        return this;
    }
    getChars(0, count, buf, 0);
    str.getChars(0, otherLen, buf, count);
    return new String(0, count + otherLen, buf);
}
```

Comment: this is a good info but why designer write in this way ?? what is the reason

Comment: This is only a reason why the NPE is thrown, but not why it was implemented this way. E.g. the equals method does check for `null` before doing anything.

Comment: but why doesn't `null + str` throw a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 4):

@Blip : 
**1) null + "ABC"**

Straight forward answer to your question is + operator in java uses StringBuilder.append method to concat the strings.

And StringBuilder.append() method treats null object as "null" String.
Hence null + "ABC" won't give Null Pointer exception but rather prints nullABC.

**2) String.concat()**

And yes, there is no null check before string.length() method in concat() function of String class. Hence it is throwing null pointer exception.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because inside `concat` method in String class, `length` method is getting invoked on passed parameter , due to which NPE is thrown.

```
public String concat(String str) {
        int otherLen = str.length();<------
        if (otherLen == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        int len = value.length;
        char buf[] = Arrays.copyOf(value, len + otherLen);
        str.getChars(buf, len);
        return new String(buf, true);
    }
```

Comment: but why doesn't `null + str` throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Because If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null"

Comment: because + toString() and concatenate the values.

Comment: You can also refer to section 5.1.11. of JLS that states `If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).`

Comment: so why doesn't `System.out.println(strNull+str)` give an output of "nullabc"?

Comment: @Blip it does gives an output of `nullabc` for the given code `String strNull = null; System.out.println(strNull + "abc");`

Answer (score 2):

`concate()` method creates `new String()` object under the hood.

where as `+` combines\ concatenates values by using `toString()` method. That's why when we use `+` it continents `"somevalue".append(null).toString()`.

for [reference](http://,%20and%20use%20Stringbuilder%20to%20concatenation%20the%20values.) see this question.

Comment: @Muneed your answer is logical among all this, can you refer me some documentation about your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`String.concat()` need an object of type `String` as a parameter.

There is no type which `null` is an `instanceof`. Refer JLS:

> 15.20.2 Type Comparison Operator instanceof
>
> RelationalExpression:
>       RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
>   At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is false.

Comment: useful info but why doesn't null + str throw a NPE

Answer (score 2):

Actual implementation of concate method is like this . this method need an object of type String as a parameter and if argument is null then it throws Null Pointer Exp.

```
public String concat(String paramString)
  {
    int i = paramString.length();
    if (i == 0) {
      return this;
    }
    int j = this.value.length;
    char[] arrayOfChar = Arrays.copyOf(this.value, j + i);
    paramString.getChars(arrayOfChar, j);
    return new String(arrayOfChar, true);
  }
```

Comment: but why doesn't `null + str` throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: because it convert null into "null" (ASCI characters 'n','u','l','l') while conversion. it is mentioned in java doc at oracle website

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class holds an array (probably an `ArrayList`) of characters. When you call `.concat()` it goes through and adds every character from the second string to the first.

If the first String is `null`, there is nothing to add to, causing a `NullPointer Exception`. Try initializing `String`s with `""`.

Comment: i think String use CharSequence. by the way i dont need a solution , i know it, i just want the reason behind it

Answer (score -3):

Initializing a null String with `""` should work.

Comment: i dont need a solution , i know it, i just want the reason behind it